# Laravel 4 - Error with "composer install": Command "optimize" is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

evertime i try install laravel4 with "composer install" i get the following error message:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Command "optimize" is not defined.
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception trace:
() at /xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:610  
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:181  
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121  
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /xxx/artisan:58
```

If i try to run the command "artisan optimize" manually, the result is the same.

The app lies on a managed hosting, maybe something is misconfigured?
I have realy no idea what's wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is composer actually installed?

Comment: yes, the "optimize" command is executed after composer has downloaded the files

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer install` on your local machine to complete the install and then try `php artisan serve` to make sure everything is working fine.

Then, you'll be able to upload your project to your server and include the `vendor` folder which is created by Composer.

Comment: this didn't work for me. composer install runs fine but `php artisan serve`
`[InvalidArgumentException]       `
`Command "serve" is not defined.`

Comment: `php artisan serve` is no longer a valid command. Just run `php artisan` and if you see a list of command options come up you'll know it's working.

Comment: I found out that I accidentally deleted the `ArtisanServiceProvider` and that's why `php artisan serve` didn't work for me.
Yes, it's no longer a valid command but this question is on laravel-4.

Answer (score 0):

probably missing a service provider. Compare your config/app.php file to the one in https://github.com/laravel/laravel/*tree/[laravel_version_num]*

Does it have the following listed under the `providers` array?: 
`Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,`